# Prevent instance variables from being cleared on memory warning

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-warning

I've got a relatively simple problem that's been evading solution for some time.  I have a view controller and an associated XIB.  The view controller is called `FooterViewController`.   `FooterViewController`'s view is set as the footer view of a tableview.

`FooterViewController`'s view includes a label for showing feedback to the user.  I would like this label to persist until its value is changed by my application.  Under normal circumstances, it does.  However, I've just begun testing with memory warnings, and I've found that after the view is unloaded in response to a memory warning, the label is cleared.

Here's what I've tried so far to solve the problem: in `FooterViewController`'s  `viewWillUnload` method, I store the label's text in an instance variable called `statusString`:

```
- (void)viewWillUnload
{
    statusString = [statusLabel text];
    testInt = 5;
    NSLog(@"View will unload; status string = %@; testInt = %d", 
            statusString, testInt);

    [super viewWillUnload];
}
```

Note that I've also set another instance variable, declared as `NSInteger testInt`, to 5.

Then, in `FooterViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, I try to set the label's text to `statusString`:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Just before setting label, statusString: %@; testInt: %d", 
            statusString, testInt);
    [statusLabel setText:statusString];
    NSLog(@"View did load.");
}
```

However, this does not work.  Further, in the log after simulating a memory warning, I see:

```
View will unload; status string = Invalid IP address Error code: 113; testInt = 5
```

(Note that "Invalid IP address Error code: 113" is the correct value for statusString)

Then, after navigating to `FooterViewController` again, I see:

```
Just before setting label, statusString: (null); testInt: 0
```

This indicates to me that for some reason, the instance variables of `FooterViewController` are being reinitialized when the view loads again.  A final note: the method `initWithNibName:bundle:` is being called each time the view must reload, though I expect this; after all, the view must be reloaded from the NIB.

So, my questions are these:

1. Why do these instance variables appear to be nullified or zeroed in the process of unloading and reloading the view?
2. If I'm doing something incorrectly that's causing this nullification, what is it?
3. If I'm not doing anything incorrectly, and this is normal behavior, how should I handle maintaining state between loads of the view?

Thanks, 
Riley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was going on, finally.  The issue was that I called the allocation and initialization methods for `FooterViewController` in its parent view controller's `viewDidLoad` method.  When the views were dumped and subsequently reloaded, my view controller was re-initialized! This destroyed the original `FooterViewController`, which maintained the instance variables I needed, and replaced it with a brand-new VC.

The solution was to move `[[FooterViewController alloc] init]` to the `init` method of `FooterViewController`'s parent VC, so that the initialization was only performed once per run cycle.

I've learned my lesson: *don't reinitialize your view controllers unless you really mean to do so.*  As such, be very careful where you put your calls to the initializer in parent view controllers.

Thanks for the help I got from the two answerers.

Answer (score 0):

The statusString looks like a weak reference, not a strong property. It can not retain the labels's text, which gets deallocated with the label when the view is unloaded. That's why you get first a correct value (before the label is deallocated), and null later (after the label has been deallocated, and the weak ref nullified). Turn your statusString into a strong property, and that ARC magic won't bite you any longer.

Comment: I've declared statusString as a strong property:

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *statusString;`

and synthesized it.  I'm still seeing the same issue, though.  I'm not sure this is exactly what's happening.

Comment: Now that's weird. I'd use the explicit setter self.statusString = statusLabel.text, instead of the direct ivar affectation, just to see, but I admit I'm puzzled, now. If the setter changes anything, we'd both have to re-read the ARC documentation :-)

Comment: Agreed.  I subbed in an explicit setter: `self.statusString = [statusLabel text]`, and am still seeing identical results.  I am under the impression that memory warnings typically release the VC's view, but not the VC itself.  Am I deluded?

Comment: No, you're not. "Private" properties should not in any way be released with the view. Stupid question: have you looked, with the "Find" command, for all occurrences of statusString in your code? Isn't it explicitly reset in some place you do not expect? That's where the Find tool is handy, when we can not see what we don't want to see :-)

Comment: Not a stupid question, but I have checked.  The only occurrences are those I've mentioned, in the header, the synthesis, `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillUnload`.  In addition, that integer I threw in, `testInt`, is behaving in the same manner as statusString.  That variable was created for the sole purpose of diagnosing this issue, so it's probably not being accidentally reset.  As a side note, I'd up vote you for your help, but I'm not allowed to yet, ha.

Comment: It's not a matter of upvote, I don't think I have the patience nor the ambition for the 666K points that some have. Another idea: click the breakpoint area next to your property synthesis: you'll see two breakpoints in the the breakpoints inspector, one for the getter, one for the setter Let's see when the setter is called?

Comment: Alright, I figured out what the issue probably is.  In the Apple Documentation, `initWithNibName:bundle:` returns a "newly initialized `UIViewController` object."  I think this means that a new instance of my `FooterViewController` is being created.  I haven't figured out a solution yet, since I need to init from the nib whenever there's a memory warning, but at least I know the problem.

Comment: Ha! Fool we are :-) I sure did not expect your controller to be reinstanciated, that's quite not common. Good to see you on the way to a proper solution, and sorry for having misled you these last few minutes!

Comment: Not at all – thanks for your help.  When I do get it sorted out, I'll post an answer to this question, if you'd like to see it.

Comment: StackOverflow should notify me :-) Good luck Riley!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to be using didRecieveMemoryWarning instead of viewDidUnload, since viewDidUnload is not guaranteed to be called in the event of a memory warning.  If the crash is exiting the app completely then you need to be writing the data to disk using something like coreData.  Save your data here and then call the super so the view will still be released.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Hmm, good thought.  You're right that I should be using `didReceiveMemoryWarning`.  However, this is not the root of my issue.  Thanks for the heads-up, though!

Comment: I should be clear that I did test this solution, and did not find it to help.  Also, I have found the actual cause and solution to my issue and will self-post it after the 8 hour wait that SO is requiring of me.  Curse my low reputation!